# Can the concrete base of a fence post be reused for a new post, or does it need to be dug up?

Tags: fence

I am repairing/replacing two leaning posts. The post dimension is 4x4', and the above-ground length is about 7 feet, so I assume the concrete is between 2-3 feet deep. The wood of the post inside the concrete base is mostly rotten. These are the pictures after removing some of the rotten posts from the concrete base.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is whether or not the current concrete base can be reused and not removed? Can I clean up the rotten wood from the base and then put a new post in? And then fill any gap with sand/gravel or expanding foam? Or must the base be completely removed before setting a new post?

On a related but slightly different issue. The next pic is from an adjacent post. This isn't leaning much but I can see there is a little gap between the base of the post and the concrete. Is there anything I can do to fix this to delay a full replacement?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reuse the concrete, but it's a terrible idea (unless your fence line was drilled into solid rock). Digging up the old foundation will probably create a massive crater that you don't want to fill with concrete. Best practice is to break off the top 6" or so of the old concrete with a sledge hammer and then bury the remaining lower part with soil. Now shift the post layout so you can dig in undisturbed soil for the new foundation.

If a section of fence is going to be too long now, then redo the post layout while anticipating the addition of an extra post. Still doesn't work? Add another post.

For the post with the gap, spray foam could work. If the gap is shallow enough so that the applicator straw of a can of spray foam can reach within an inch or two of the bottom, then go for it. In the more likely scenario of a deep gap, there's a product called "anchor cement" that I would use. This stuff is typically used to fill the gap around ornamental steel where it embeds into holes bored into concrete. It mixes up pretty runny (runny enough to self level) and expands a little as it sets instead of shrinking like concrete. 20 pounds of anchor cement costs about 20 USD in the US.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done, to keep the old concrete.

Place a 3 foot marker on a new post and see if you can get it 3 feet deep, if not keep digging/cleaning.

I installed a fence 30 Years ago, using pressure treated wood then coated it with Tar, and set in concrete. It is still standing without indication of rot. I paid special attention to tar cover the face that sits on the earth in hole, preventing it to soak up the water. That part is more water absorbent than the sides of the post due to pressure treatment process.

On your last picture you can see that post is already absorbing the water from the bottom.

Comment: The old concrete looks broken though.